# Stuck on parsing JSON the right way

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

i've searched and tried many things but I cant get the following:

```
{"Plaats" : ["{"isEmpty":true,"isWhite":false,"isBlack":false}"]}
```

That's my current response but I need it to be in this format:

```
{"Plaats" : [{"isEmpty":true,"isWhite":false,"isBlack":false}]}
```

So without the extra quotes basically.

Here's my C# code:

```
public class Vaag
{
    public bool isEmpty { get; set; }
    public bool isWhite { get; set; }
    public bool isBlack { get; set; }
}

var tempObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_Context.JsonBord);
dynamic JsonObj = tempObj;
var testt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Vaag() { isEmpty = true, isWhite = false, isBlack = false });
JsonObj[0][0] = testt;
string result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonObj);
return result.Replace(@"\", ""); ;
```

Comment: None of that is valid is JSON, what are all the zeros all about?

Comment: @RyanThomas ignore all the zeros for now, they will all be {"isEmpty":true,"isWhite":false,"isBlack":false}

Comment: As @RyanThomas says >>it is not json<< so you can not parse it. Where did you get that "string" from?

Comment: @FrankNielsen i edited my question, it looks like this actually. The extra quoties is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the class you are using to deserialize your JSON needs to look like your JSON. Example below.

```
public class VaagCollection
{
    public List<Vaag> Plaats { get; set }

}
public class Vaag
{
    public bool isEmpty { get; set; }
    public bool isWhite { get; set; }
    public bool isBlack { get; set; }
}

var tempObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VaagCollection>(_Context.JsonBord);


tempObj.Plaats.Add(new Vaag() { isEmpty = true, isWhite = false, isBlack = false });
string result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempObj);
```

Comment: We are on some track, but  Vaag is defined as string json. So it must be `List<string> Plaats`. and then afterwards deserialize that to an object.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix json in json (something like this):

```
public class Vaag
{
    public string Plaats { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<VaagFlags> PlaatsFlags => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VaagFlags[]>(Plaats);
}

public class VaagFlags
{
    public bool isEmpty { get; set; }
    public bool isWhite { get; set; }
    public bool isBlack { get; set; }
}

var vaag = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vaag>(jsonString);
```